# Does Athena Data Source equal to Athena Data Catalog in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

In Athena, I can create Data Sources:

[image]

In the IAM Policy of Athena, there is no concept of "data source", but a permission named "getDataCatalog":
[image]

So my question here is that does this data catalog equal to the data source I added in the Athena? Shall I use the data source name as the name of data catalog in the ARN? Are they equivalence?

Comment: I got it, if I use lambda connector, the lambda function name is the name of catalog.